# how to speed up R session? (allocating more resources)

Tags: r, performance, cpu

I am doing classification in R by package e1071. my dataset includes 16000 training examples with 4000 testing. number of features: 4097.
this classification takes an hour for training. I checked my cpu usages during classification and realized that only 30-40% of my cpu is busy with R-studio.
Can I allocate more cpu power to R-session?
Thanks.

Comment: If you're on Windows you can increase your `memory.limit()`

Comment: It may be because your functions are not running in parallel..? I don't know the package though.

Comment: @RichardScriven yes i am using windows. but over 2GB of memory (RAM) already allocated. I wanna speed up by cpu.

Comment: @docendodiscimus, e1071 is SVM package for supervised classification. I am very doubt that functions are running in parallel. how can I know that?

Comment: Look into Task view on high performance computing 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: Use the OpenBLAS can speed up your CPU to 100%

Comment: 30-40% CPU usage seems strange. Either you have 2 CPUs or 4 CPUs. Thus, you should see about 50 % or 25 % CPU usage by the R process. Anyway, as far as I can see `e1071::svm` doesn't support parallelization. (2GB RAM is not much. Are you sure that you are not RAM limited?)

Comment: @Roland, my cpu is intel i3 with 2cores 3.32GH. I have 4GB ram, sometimes for classification it goes over 3GB. so i dont think there is any RAM limitation. but cpu performance in the task manager is below 40%.

Comment: The processor probably has 4 threads, wich means a process can use 25 % of the CPU. The rest is not used by R itself, but by other applications.

Comment: @Roland, yes you right. Is there any way to run by full threads?

Comment: @qjgods, thanks for introducing openBLAS. Could you tell me how to use openBLAS in R in Windows x64? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the OpenBLAS in R in Windows x64

Open the url http://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/

Open the the latest version folder

download OpenBLAS-v0.2.13-Win64-int32.zip and mingw64_dll.zip

Unpack the "OpenBLAS-v0.2.13-Win64-int32.zip" find "libopenblas.dll" and rename this file to "Rblas.dll",copy the file to the path like this "\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64"(Remember to backup)
Unpack the "mingw64_dll.zip" and copy all the DLL to the same path "\R\R-3.1.2\bin\x64"

Finally,just enjoy the speed of calculation

```
x<-matrix(1:(6000*6000),6000,6000)
system.time(tmp<-x%*%x)
```

Using these two commands to contrast before and after the change